# can we deploy wiremock code in jboss server

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss, wiremock

I am trying to mock the objects returning from the server to the client. So I need to deploy my Wiremock Code in Server. So is this possible or is there any other way to achieve this scenario?

And I am completely new to Wiremock. So How can I run this on JBoss?

I followed the method of running wiremock-standalone jar and I am able to capture my request and response.

But my main question is, can I able to get mock responses from @Test methods?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Arquillian](https://www.baeldung.com/arquillian) to test JBoss. You can test microservices using this approach and use Jboss Forge ~ another tool, to speed up the testing/dev. The start guide with Forge [is here](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/).

You will just need to add on the pom.xml the dependency for Arquillian:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion @Francisco, but my requirement is to use Wiremock in Jboss.

Comment: No problem Sachin.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any library clash you can use the standalone version of WireMock. I used it with wildly (JBoss AS) adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
   <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
   <version>2.27.2</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

For further information see http://wiremock.org/docs/download-and-installation/

What you've done with wiremock-standalone is very similar to what arquillian does in an integration test. You write your server code then you test it inside a container using a client extension.
Try reading the documentation at http://arquillian.org/arquillian-core/